# Is this question correctly marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

[Removing the splash screen on shutdown an startup. I want to be able to see the processes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120898/removing-the-splash-screen-on-shutdown-an-startup-i-want-to-be-able-to-see-the)

As I understand it's about disabling splash screen while second one is about booting in text mode, which are two different things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, they are two different things. I have reopened the question.